# php preg_replace text between one tag

Tags: php, regex

I have a website which create many forms as following:

```
<form action="link1" method="post" >
<form action="link2" method="post" >
<form action="link3" method="post" > etc ...
```

Now all I want is to change the whole text between the form tag so it will look like this:

```
<form id="link">
```

I already tested many tricks but I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: post here what you've tried!

Comment: You need to provide sample input, output, and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ?

```
$mixed = preg_replace('~(<form [^>]+>)(.+?)+(</form>)~i', '$1the form HTML replacement$3', '<form method="post">the form HTML content to replace</form>');
```

I used this link to test it http://micmap.org/php-by-example/en/function/preg_replace

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're exactly trying to do, but you should consider **DOM**` for the task.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <form action="link1" method="post" >
     <form action="link2" method="post" >
     <form action="link3" method="post" >
');

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('form') as $node) {
   $node->removeAttribute('action');
   $node->removeAttribute('method');
   $node->setAttribute('id', 'somelink');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that your code generate an array $links[]  like this:

```
$links = array("link1", "link2", "link3");
```

so your code would look something like this :

```
$re = "/\\<form action=\\\"([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\\\" method=\\\"post\\\" \\>/"; 

foreach($links as $value)
 {

    $str = "<form action=\"$value\" method=\"post\" >"; 
    $subst = "<form id=\"$1\"> <input type=\"text\"></form>"; 

    $new_link = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
    echo $new_link;
    echo "<br>";
 }
```

[click here to see it in action](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4246b03a5abc1566470dd729960b6fdf7c693c5d)  
or [here](http://code.runnable.com/VY8nfkBKavtbLSq3/regex28062015-for-php) (if the first link is dead)

and here is the $re variable in details :

[image]

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
preg_replace("~<form\s.*?>~i",'<form id="link">', '<form action="link3" method="post" >');
```